# How to minimise the amount of concrete needed for a shed foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, shed, masonry, concrete-block

I’m looking to build a 6m by 3m shed in the back garden. It will be jammed in between 3 neighbours’ gardens, so it will have to be less than 2.5m high. Roof will most likely be a low grade pitch with corrugated plastic (so not heavy). My budget for this is very small, so I’d need to recycle old materials as much as possible. I have a good amount of reclaimed bricks, and a friend has an old pre-cast concrete panel garage, which I could potentially have as well. I don’t think it will be large enough, so I might end up using a combination of both. Which is fine for me as any neighbour (incl. me) would only see 1 side anyway.

I am clueless as to what to do with the foundations, so I was hoping for some help. I don’t need planning or building permission, and since it’s only a shed I guess I can do whatever works. Which for me would be whatever is cheapest. Access to the rear garden is limited, and pumping concrete expensive. So that’s a no-go. Mixing concrete in the back garden is not impossible, but will be back breaking. So I’d like to keep the amount of concrete needed down.

I have plenty of hardcore and ideally I’d like to use some of the bricks to do some sort of masonry foundations, covered with a small amount of concrete if needed. Or use some of the pre-cast concrete panels. Or really anything to keep the amount of concrete I would have to use down. Any advice on how I would be able to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I’d like to stick bricks or a very thin layer of concrete and DPC down on the floor anyway to keep my tools dry.

Comment: The shed doesn't need to be on a concrete pad, as long as it has a floor.  If you build the shed to have a wooden floor, then you can use a few blocks or a bed of gravel to keep the wooden floor off of the wet ground.

Comment: Whatever floor material you end up using, always put down a vapor barrier. [Just noticed how old this question was, sorry, still applicable though.]

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to minimize use of concrete, **don't use any.** I have 4 sheds that have been sitting for 14 years on sections of pressure treated wood, set on top of the ground - and a 5th that's on 4 pressure treated wood posts set into the ground. No concrete at all. Wooden floors (not pressure treated - only the ground-contact wood is PT.)

Nice and dry.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Could I build a brick shed on top of these though? What would I use as foundation for the walls then? These will be heavy.